# facebook app asking permissions to users have problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Not asking permissions when we login i am given permissions as email,user_friends.when we run the app it asks login.After login not asking any permission like user_friends etc...For the Admin users it asks the permissions.And my app not submitted to the review.Please Help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question in the last two sentences...

If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers. To access additional elements of a person's Facebook profile, you will need to submit your app for review.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review